# Best Python Library for Downloading and Extracting Addresses

Tags: python, email, pop3

I've just been given a project which involves the following steps

1. Grab an email from a POP3 address
2. Open an attachment from the email
3. Extract the To: email address
4. Add this to a global suppression list

I'd like to try and do this in Python even though I could it in PHP in half the time (this is because I dont know anywhere near as much Python as PHP)

My question would be.

Can anyone recommend a Python library for interacting with email in the way described above?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Two bits from the standard library: [poplib](http://docs.python.org/library/poplib.html) to grab the email via POP3, [email](http://docs.python.org/library/email.html) to slice and dice it as you wish.

Comment: Yeah, Python comes batteries included, as usual. For the global suppression list, use shelves so you'll have persistance.